# Issue in converting Base64string into string

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert base64 string in to string format but I always get nil. My base64 string is "NWQwMDU2ZjhiZjRjYmI2M2MxZTI0NzQzNjAxMjMxMzAyMDh8NjAxMjMxMzAyMDh8NWQwMDU2Zjhi\nZjRjYmI2M2MxZTI0NzQzfDYwMTIzMTMwMjA4fG5hdmlnYXRpb25UZXN0MDA1fDIwMTktMDYtMjEg\nMDk6MzQ6MDB8MA==\n"

After decoding, Is suppose to look like this "5d0056f8bf4cbb63c1e2474360123130208|60123130208|5d0056f8bэ͌Ŕ٥ѥQشĂs3C�". 
Here is my code event I tried to remove the "=\n" from string but not succeed.

```
 func qrScanningSucceededWithCode(_ str: String?) {
    scanTicketView.qrData = QRData(codeString: str)
    let charsToRemove: Set<Character> = Set("=\n")
    let newNumberCharacters = String(str!.filter { !charsToRemove.contains($0) })
    let decodedString = String(data: Data(base64Encoded: newNumberCharacters)!, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(decodedString)
}
```

Comment: the == is the padding, which is required. just remove the \n

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
let string = "NWQwMDU2ZjhiZjRjYmI2M2MxZTI0NzQzNjAxMjMxMzAyMDh8NjAxMjMxMzAyMDh8NWQwMDU2Zjhi\nZjRjYmI2M2MxZTI0NzQzfDYwMTIzMTMwMjA4fG5hdmlnYXRpb25UZXN0MDA1fDIwMTktMDYtMjEg\nMDk6MzQ6MDB8MA==\n"

let joined = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: joined) {
    String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}
```